# Python modify nested dictionary value at list of keys

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, nested

I have a dictionary like:

`{"value1": {}, "value2": {"value3": {}, "value4": {}, "value5": {"value6": {}}}}`

And a list of keys:

`["value2", "value4"]`

How can I modify the dictionary such that the key `"value4"` (in the dictionary with the key `"value2"`) is changed to `"value4*"`? I only want the last key to be affected, so `"value2"` would not be changed.

I have tried using `list(map(dictionary.get, keys))` but this does not do what I want.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I have tried to keep this very short, please tell me if I have cut out too much.

Comment: Yes, you did cut too much. What do you mean by "value4*"?

Comment: @RafaelBarros OK I'll try to edit it to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: Do you want to change `value2` and `value4` or only `value4`?

Comment: @Cleb only `value4`

Comment: This is something you should state clearly as a list suggests that you want to change all keys in this list which - I think - also @Ajax1234 assumes.

Comment: @Cleb I'll edit the post. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```
new_d = ["value2", "value4"]
d = {"value1": {}, "value2": {"value3": {}, "value4": {}, "value5": {"value6": {}}}}
def update(data):
  return {a if a != new_d[-1] else f'{a}*':b if not isinstance(b, dict) else update(b) for a, b in data.items()}

print(update(d))
```

Output:

```
{'value1': {}, 'value2': {'value3': {}, 'value4*': {}, 'value5': {'value6': {}}}}
```

Edit: without `f-string`:

```
def update(data):
  return {a if a != new_d[-1] else a+"*":b if not isinstance(b, dict) else update(b) for a, b in data.items()}
```

Comment: Hmm... It gives me invalid syntax at the first single quote after `return`. I'm using py3 btw. Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: @Jachdich That is because the first solution is using an `f-string` for formatting the new key, which is only available in Python3.7. Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Just one thing, is it possible to only update the last key? So only `value4` changes and not `value2`?

Comment: @Jachdich Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Other option but different logic.

Works on second level keys, it changes only `value4` directly under `value2`:

```
dct = {"value1": {}, "value2": {"value3": {}, "value4": {}, "value5": {"value4": {}}}}
keyz = ["value2", "value4"]

print(dct)

def append_star(dct, keyz):
  dct[keyz[0]][keyz[1] + '*'] = dct[keyz[0]][keyz[1]]
  del dct[keyz[0]][keyz[1]]

append_star(dct, keyz)
```

Or in this case, `value2` directly under `value2`, not `value2` at the higher level:

```
dct = {"value1": {}, "value2": {"value2": {}, "value4": {}, "value5": {"value4": {}}}}
keyz = ["value2", "value2"]
{'value1': {}, 'value2': {'value4': {}, 'value5': {'value4': {}}, 'value2*': {}}}
```